# Problem in loading mailR package in R version 3.6.1

Tags: r, sendmailr

Since I've developed my R into 3.6.1, mailR package is not working anymore getting this error: there is no package called ‘R.utils’.
Installing this package does not work either. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: How did you update your R and your packages? If it can't find `R.utils`, you can just install it with `install.packages("R.utils")`. Not sure why this dependency wouldn't have been installed.

Comment: I already tried to install R.utils the same way you said but it has a problem with loading it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem loading it? You need to be able to install all the dependencies for a given package before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The package `mailR` depends on `rJava` package.

"*It’s a wrapper around Apache Commons Email, an email library built on top of the Java Mail API. Due to this, mailR has a dependency on the rJava package, a low-level interface to Java VM.*", [source](https://mailtrap.io/blog/r-send-email/).

Therefore, you need to install the package `rJava` in order to use `mailR`, and you need to have Java Runtime Environment on your operating system in order for `rJava` to work properly. I recommend using either [Oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GDRAD/java.htm#BGBFJHAB) or [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/install/).

After you have these installed, you need to include both libraries:

```
library(rJava)
library(mailR)
```

Note that you might run into an error that says `Error in library(mailR) : there is no package called ‘mailR’` even though you have it installed. In this case, restart your PC, run R Studio again and then include the library, and there should be no issues.